# Putting an html.beginform inside a bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want to place an html.beginform **inside** a bootstrap modal which posts to a controller action method.

The bootstrap modal comes up fine, but when I click on the "Save" button, it doesn't post to my method.

Notice I have the correct ViewModel name and the HttpPost method decorated on my controller Edit method.

Notice the below image showing what the link is in the lower left which seems to be a "GET" (see the "2" at the end of the link):
[image]

I got the following info from Fiddler after submitting the "Save" button.

```
GET http://localhost:7683/__browserLink/requestData/c7214b476210499781860a178a6b7607?version=2 HTTP/1.1
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Referer: http://localhost:7683/Projects/Project/Edit/2?Name=A%26C+CaseTracker&Description=Keeps+track+of+all+dental+cases.&CustomerID=2&CategoryID=10&PriorityID=1&StatusID=4&Quote=509.00&Notes=Plus+maintenance+costs.
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: localhost:7683
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

After placing a breakpoint on my "HTTPGET" method, that's where it's hitting **even though in the form I'm telling it to do a POST:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Project", FormMethod.Post))
```

**Can someone please inform me what I'm doing wrong?**

### Here is my html:

```
@model YeagerTechDB.Models.Project

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Project";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit Project</h2>

<div class="modal" id="projectEditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="projectModal-label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="projectModal-label">Edit Project: Project: @Model.ProjectID</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Project", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                   <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-offset-1 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" })
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "ProjectName" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "control-label col-offset-1 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" })
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Description" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.Email, new { @class = "control-label col-offset-1 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" })
                            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Customers, "CustomerID", "Email", Model.CustomerID), "-- Select Customer --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category.CategoryDescription, new { @class = "control-label col-offset-1 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" })
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryDescription", Model.CategoryID), "-- Select Category --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Priority.PriorityDescription, new { @class = "control-label col-offset-1 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" })
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PriorityID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Priorities, "PriorityID", "PriorityDescription", Model.PriorityID), "-- Select Priority --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PriorityID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status.StatusDescription, new { @class = "control-label col-offset-1 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" })
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StatusID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Statuses, "StatusID", "StatusDescription", Model.StatusID), "-- Select Status --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StatusID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quote, new { @class = "control-label col-offset-1 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" })
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quote, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Quote" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quote, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quote, new { @class = "control-label col-offset-1 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" })
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Notes" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedDate, new { @class = "control-label col-offset-1 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" })
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" } })
                            </div>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UpdatedDate, new { @class = "control-label col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" })
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UpdatedDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSaveProject">Save</button>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $('#projectEditModal').modal('show');
        });
    </script>
}
```

### Here is my Edit post method:

```
 [HttpPost]
               public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(Project project)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //await db.EditProjectAsync(project);
            }

            List<CustomerDDL> customerList = await db.GetCustomerDDLAsync();
            ViewBag.Customers = customerList;

            List<Category> categoryList = await db.GetCategoriesAsync();
            ViewBag.Categories = categoryList;

            List<Priority> priorityList = await db.GetPrioritiesAsync();
            ViewBag.Priorities = priorityList;

            List<Status> statusList = await db.GetStatusesAsync();
            ViewBag.Statuses = statusList;

            return View(project);
        }
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem is exactly, but here are some questions that might help narrow it down:  1.) Show us what your MVC route configuration looks like.  It's unusual that the URL in the browser is localhost/Projects/Project/Edit.  There's an extra segment in that path that I usually don't see.  2.) What is the name of your C# controller class?  3.) You don't happen to have version of this live on a production server that we could look at, do you?

Comment: You have not shown you main view (that you load the modal from) but I suspect that may also have a form tag in it.

Comment: Rajeev, in regards to #1, that's because I'm using "Areas" in my project. So, the Area is "Project" and the controller is "Project". For #2, it's "ProjectController.cs". For #3,  I do have it on a website "YeagerTech.azurewebsites.net", BUT, I'm able to successfully do all of this using a url.action which kicks which kicks off an Ajax request and works fine. I wanted to see if I can use a BeginForm instead of writing the Ajax scripting.

Comment: Stephen, the modal is loaded via JS in the View that is trying to do the BeginForm. " $('#projectEditModal').modal('show');".

Comment: Bottom line: is it feasible to put an html.Beginform inside a bootstrap modal for a POST. From what I'm trying to do, it doesn't seem like it's a possibility. If it is possible, what am I doing wrong. If you need any other info, please let me know and I'll be happy to provide it... btw, the you can edit the data on the site since it's only test data. But, again, this is without the html.beginform.

Comment: It is with the following: "<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnCloseProject" data-url="@Url.Action("Index", "Project", new { area = "Projects" })"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"></span>Close</button>". Notice the data-url that I use with the url.action which basically is used in the JS Ajax for the id value and posts the form data with Ajax. Bam, works fine, but I'm finding out I can't do it with the html.beginform and I'd love to know either why or why not....

Comment: btw, instead of "Close", it's "Save".

Comment: @sagesky36, Is the view code you have shown the main view, or is this view being loaded into another view (this issue is often the result of nested forms which is invalid html and not supported)

Comment: Yes, the View code I have shown is actually the main view. It is an "Edit" view which pops up the modal as soon as you get into the View because of the $('#projectEditModal').modal('show'); JS statement.

Comment: If that's the case there is nothing in your code which suggests this should not be posting correctly. Are you sure this is all the relevant code? (and it seems a strange UI - why would you use a dialog instead of just rendering the form in the view?)

Comment: Seems like the reason why it's going to the GET instead of the POST, is because the "GET" form has the "id" option on the route where the Modal is. Because of this, I'll have to do the processing via Ajax as described earlier in my present project.

Comment: @sagesky36, That has nothing to do with it. There is something else in your code causing the issue.

Comment: note that right before the "post", there is a "get" with an id value and brings data into the modal form. When I try and save back the form, it goes to the "get" instead of the "post" because the ID value is still on the "Save" button when I hover over it. Is there anything I'm doing wrong with the way I have the "Save" button set up where it doesn't get to the "post" action method? Note that if I execute all of this via strictly Ajax and javascript, it works fine, but I'd like to do it through a BeginForm post. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to take out the `data-dismiss="modal"` from the `div class="modal-footer"`. I had the same problem and that worked for me. Hope it does for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <h2>Edit Project</h2>
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Project", FormMethod.Post))
                {
<div class="modal" id="projectEditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="projectModal-label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="projectModal-label">Edit Project: Project: @Model.ProjectID</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                   <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-offset-1 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" })
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "ProjectName" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "control-label col-offset-1 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" })
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Description" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.Email, new { @class = "control-label col-offset-1 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" })
                            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Customers, "CustomerID", "Email", Model.CustomerID), "-- Select Customer --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category.CategoryDescription, new { @class = "control-label col-offset-1 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" })
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryDescription", Model.CategoryID), "-- Select Category --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Priority.PriorityDescription, new { @class = "control-label col-offset-1 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" })
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PriorityID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Priorities, "PriorityID", "PriorityDescription", Model.PriorityID), "-- Select Priority --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PriorityID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status.StatusDescription, new { @class = "control-label col-offset-1 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" })
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StatusID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Statuses, "StatusID", "StatusDescription", Model.StatusID), "-- Select Status --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StatusID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quote, new { @class = "control-label col-offset-1 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" })
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quote, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Quote" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quote, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quote, new { @class = "control-label col-offset-1 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" })
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Notes" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedDate, new { @class = "control-label col-offset-1 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" })
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" } })
                            </div>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UpdatedDate, new { @class = "control-label col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" })
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UpdatedDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSaveProject">Save</button>
                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 }
```

Comment: Nope, still goes to the GET and not the POST.

Comment: may be this link can help to you https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/07/23/async-actions-in-aspnet-mvc-4.aspx